# Cypher returning multiple rows per match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am querying neo4j with cypher and am getting two rows per match:

```
MATCH (g:Group {Name: "Goliath_Treasury237"})-[w:MEMBER]->(a:Account)<-[y:ACCOUNT]-(p:Person)-[MANAGER*0..1]->(b:Person) 
WHERE NOT p.staffID = b.staffID 
MATCH (g:Group {Name: "Goliath_Treasury237"})-[j:MEMBER]->(v:Account)<-[x:ACCOUNT]-(p:Person)-[f:DEP*0..1]->(d:Department) 
RETURN  p.GivenName, p.Surname, p.staffID, p.CorpT, b.staffID, d.Name
```

I'm trying to get the information for both the department and the boss of a person which I'm struggling with declaratively unless I do the double match. This returns two rows for each match where a person has a boss, one with their ID as their bosses ID and one with the correct bosses id. For people without a boss I get one row back but the bosses id is their own.

If I remove the variable length path for boss then I get one row for each individual but no row where someone doesn't have a boss.

I'm at a loss now, any help would be great!

Comment: I get the double rows even in the mud simpler case:

MATCH (g:Group {Name: "Goliath_Treasury237"})-[w:MEMBER]->(a:Account)<-[y:ACCOUNT]-(p:Person)-[MANAGER*0..1]->(b:Person) return  p.GivenName, p.Surname, p.staffID, p.CorpT, b.staffID

This seems strange, I'd assumed it was a problem with the double MATCH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several things we can fix here.

For one, you don't need the second match to start over from the beginning, you can reuse the same `p` node without needing all the stuff before. You also don't need to have a variable on every node and relationship if you're not going to use or return it in some way.

You can use an OPTIONAL MATCH when you don't want the match to filter out rows, newly-introduced variables in the OPTIONAL MATCH will be null if the match fails.

Something like this should work:

```
MATCH (:Group {Name: "Goliath_Treasury237"})-[:MEMBER]->(:Account)<-[:ACCOUNT]-(p:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[MANAGER]->(b:Person) 
WHERE NOT p.staffID = b.staffID 
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:DEP]->(d:Department) 
RETURN  p.GivenName, p.Surname, p.staffID, p.CorpT, b.staffID, d.Name
```

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed work. I think I better understand Optional Matches now also.